# Problem with adding an additional javascript to a page

Tags: jquery

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');

// use this to pull the divs in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow DIV:first');

// uncomment below to pull the divs randomly
// var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
// var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
// var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}
```

I added this script to a page with additional js, it was working stand alone but now its errors in firebug, newbie, thx for any help...

```
$(function() {
     setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

The error message is:

```
$ is not defined index.html()()index.html (line 126)
$(function() {
```

Comment: what exactly is the original page, what did you add to it? what library are you using?

Comment: Do not use variables beginning with $, especially if you are using frameworks, to avoid confusion.

Comment: i agree that you should not use variables beginning with $ ...if line 126 is where you define the callback, your syntax is fine and the problem must be elsewhere.  maybe post your entire file

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure the new page is including jquery?

If so, add the code in piece by piece to narrow down where the problem is happening. Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), although you don't mention it.  Did you load the jQuery library?  The [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) library also defines a `$()` function.

Comment: yea 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-fluid16.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/thickbox.js"></script>

Comment: also double check that you are not including both prototype and jquery

Answer (score 0):

You are loading jquery AFTER your javascript code executes.  That simply won't work.  Put your javascript in an exeternal file and load it after jquery.